# Python IOError exception when unzipping archive with deep directory structure

Tags: python, filenames, zip, ioerror

I am having following error when trying to extract zip file using zipfile module's extractall method:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 964, in extractall
self.extract(zipinfo, path, pwd)
File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 952, in extract
return self._extract_member(member, path, pwd)
File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 996, in _extract_member
target = file(targetpath, "wb")

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\GITHUBDB\\C++\\FellowTraveler
_Open-Transactions\\FellowTraveler-Open-Transactions-846a939\\sample-data\\no_ba
skets\\client_data\\purse\\tBy5mL14qSQXCJK7Uz3WlTOKRP9M0JZksA3Eg7EnnQ1\\T1Q3wZWg
eTUoaUvn9m1lzIK5tn5wITlzxzrGNI8qtaV\\CvHGtfOOKzQKL5hFL7J4iF5yAodVKhS1rxPzME5R9XA'
```

This is happening because of Windows 260-char limit on path.
Doing cd is not an option, most of path is from archive itself.
I have read about "\\?\" prefix, but adding it to extractall parameter doesn't work, it fails on os.mkdir inside zipfile module.

Fixing zipfile.py with "\\?\" seems possible, but an ugly solution.

Any ideas, please ?

Comment: Extract it at the root `D:`, or don't use full paths, or try to use sensible directory names.

Comment: I can't use any other directory names :) because archives are from external source.
Extracting to D:\ will save me just 13 symbols... it won't help.

Comment: You could subclass `ZipFile` to override [`_extract_member`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Lib/zipfile.py#l965). Maybe truncate all long directory names to 10 characters + a hash of the original name for uniqueness.

Comment: Do you need the entire tree or just the files?

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, there's a way to support long file paths.
Just make sure your path is unicode, absolute and add the `\\?\` prefix. For example:

```
zip = ZipFile(zip_filename)
zip.extractall(u'\\\\?\\D:\\a_long_path')
```

I've tested it with the `ZipFile` class on python 2.7 and it works perfectly.

You can read more about file naming on Windows [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have to encode the path to unicode, but I have to change the path to absolute path and add the '\\?\' before this absolute path.